# lua test and assign inside loop control

Tags: lua, luasql

Is there / please suggest a syntax to achieve a compact 'test and assign' in lua?

Consider this segment from luasql examples ( http://keplerproject.org/luasql/examples.html )

```
-- retrieve a cursor
cur = assert (con:execute"SELECT name, email from people")
-- print all rows, the rows will be indexed by field names
row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")
while row do
  print(string.format("Name: %s, E-mail: %s", row.name, row.email))
  -- reusing the table of results
  row = cur:fetch (row, "a")
end
```

I am learning lua, and really struggling to accept the duplicated call to cur:fetch().  I see that repeat/until trivially fixes the issue, but then it seems I have to test twice:

```
repeat
  row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")
  if row then
    print ...
  end
until nil == row
```

I consider this less error prone for the case of 'row = ...' getting more complex, but still seems inelegant.

Comment: `row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")` and `row = cur:fetch (row, "a")` are not exact duplicates.

Comment: nice catch, I had not recognised that efficiency feature of the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the first loop to this:

```
local row = {}
while row do
  row = cur:fetch(row, "a")
end
```

EDIT: The [sample page](http://keplerproject.org/luasql/examples.html) hits at a possible solution using [iterators](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html) and a for loop, like @doukremt is suggesting. Unfortunately it also contains a couple errors (it assumes that the rows get "unpacked" in the second example but not in the first, does not declare everything `local`, and omits more parenthesis than it's sane to in a sample code). Here's how you can transform a cursor in an iterator:

```
local iterate = function(cur)
  return function() return cur:fetch() end
end
```

Here's how you use it:

```
local cur = assert(con:execute("SELECT name, email from people"))

for row in iterate(cur) do
  print(string.format ("%s: %s", row.name, row.email))
end
```

I must warn you that iterators are in general more expensive than while/repeat loops. Execute performance tests if you are worried about speed.

Comment: this seems equivalent to the repeat/until form with a different initialisation?  it successfully eliminates one of the cur:fetch() calls, but still requires a redundant test of the result before using it (printing, in this case).

Comment: Thank You! I had tried to implement an equivalent to the iterator section in the sample but could not get it to work - your complete example is especially helpful.   Minor typo (s/cur/curr/) in line 3 of "here's how you use it".

Comment: Glad it helped you. I fixed the typo

Answer (score 3):

Just use a for loop:

```
row = {}
for row  in cur:fetch(row, "a") do
    -- ...
end
```

The call to `fetch()` returns a pointer to the table you pass as argument, so you could as well do:

```
row = {}
for foobar in cur:fetch(row, "a") ...
```

The important point is that `fetch()` returns nil when there are no more rows, so you just need to check for that, which a for loop does implicitly.

Comment: Have tried several variants here and generally get 'attempt to call a table value' at the for / in line?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
while true do
  local row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")
  if row then
    print ...
  else
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: my preference would be something like `while true do   local row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")   if not row then break end` (sorry can't work out multiline code formatting in comments) but it is still not the readability that I was hoping for

Comment: would +1 a second time if I could as this, with my 1-line break modification above, is actually the form I am using in my code (due to kikito's comments about performance).